# How can SKScene communicate with its container SKView?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I have a `SKScene` presented in a `SKView`. I want a way to send info from the scene to the view, for later use with the controller.

For example, consider having the View Controller as the delegate of the `SKView`, and the `SKView` needs to notify the `UIViewController` when a certain part of its presented scene is tapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKScene` has a handy instance member `.view` for just this situation. To access standard `SKView` methods and properties you can use it like:

```
self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecognizer)
```

If your containing view is an `SKView` subclass, you can downcast `.view` to access custom methods:

```
if let myView = self.view as? MyCustomViewClass {
    myView.sceneWasTapped()
}
```

Keep in mind that `.view` is an optional; it will be nil if the scene hasn't been added to a view yet. Scenes call `didMove(to view: SKView)` when they are added to a view, so that's a good place to do things that rely on a `.view` existing.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot!